# I want to write math expression in file

Tags: python, string, file, math

ı want to write that command but it is not working

```
for k in range 900 :
    l=len(str(a[k])    **a[ ] is a string which gives random float numbers**

 f.write("\n*l")   **ı need to write space as the number of string length**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiplication needs to be *on* the string, not in it.

```
f.write("\n" * l)
```

Comment: how can ı read line ? ı want to read a specific part of the line

for example c.readline(3,5) I want to read between third and fifth characters ( bits)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you get length correctly, problem is to write to file.

All you need to do is save to string first and write that string into file.

```
temp = ''
for k in range 900 :
    l=len(str(a[k])    **a[ ] is a string which gives random float numbers**
    temp = temp + str(l) + "\n"  # store all your values to temp string

f.write(temp)   # then write than temp string into file
```

Comment: that comands for what ? ı dont want output to my length of string

Comment: then what you need to write ?

Comment: how can ı read line ? ı want to read a specific part of the line for example c.readline(3,5) I want to read between third and fifth characters ( bits)